# Mysql query stumped - add value to previous date value

Tags: mysql

Good day - i have nowhere to begin this query!!

I have a row - columns are date,product,value

values

| nr | ipdate | product | market_value_1 | value calc | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | ASISA | 0.9990975600702915638 | "0.90975600702915638"/"100"-1 | 0.9909024399297084 |
| 2 | 2021-01-02 | ASISA | 0.9990972000702915638 | "0.9909024399297084"/"0.9990972000702915638" | 0.9917978349453821 |
| 3 | 2021-01-03 | ASISA | 0.9890972000702915638 | "0.9890972000702915638"/"0.9917978349453821" | 0.9972770308827713 |

I need to start with 2021-01-01 and do Market_value_1/100  - 1
then next date market value /previous date value
then next date market value /previous date value
then next date market value /previous date value

This
is the code i am trying

```
SELECT product,ipdate,
       market_value_1 mv1,
       row_num,
       @running,
       (@running := market_value_1/(SELECT IF(row_num = 1, 100, @running)))  AS running,
       ROUND(@running,8)
FROM (SELECT id,
             ipdate,
             product,
             market_value_1,
             (@row_num := @row_num + 1) AS row_num
      FROM report_combined
     GROUP BY product,ipdate
      ORDER BY product,ipdate) AS a"
```

But my row wont reset to 1 on every product change

Comment: Is it safe to assume that each `ipdate` is unique? Also, can you please be more clear about the `value_calc` column formula?

Comment: Yes each ip date is unique - its daily investments
The first day will always be the value 100. Then first cal will be market_value_1/100 -1 to get that days value
next day value will be next row value = (market_value_1/previous date "value")-1

This will be grouped by product,ipdate

So it needs to recalculate with each new product

Comment: What's the reason for `GROUP BY product, ipdate`? If there are multiple rows per product/ipdate, which value of `market_value_1` should be used? Your explanation of the calculation - `market_value_1/100 -1` would make the first row `0.9990975600702915638/100 - 1` which is `-0.99000902439929708436200` or `-0.99000902` when rounded to 8 decimal places. Please update your question so that it makes sense. Instead of tracking row number, store the previous row's product.

Answer (score 0):

Your current query is nondeterministic as you have `GROUP BY product, ipdate` but columns `id` and `market_value_1` are not contained in aggregate functions. On this basis, I am assuming that the grouping serves no purpose and leaving it out. I am also using the calculation as described in your comment, not the original question, but you can amend that as needed when you figure out what the calculation is supposed to be.

To make your current query reset for each product you can compare to previous product, instead of using a row number:

```
SELECT
    @row_num := IF(product = @prev_product, @row_num + 1, 1) AS nr,
    product,
    ipdate,
    market_value_1,
    (@running := market_value_1/(IF(product <> @prev_product, 100, @running)) - 1) AS running,
    ROUND(@running, 8),
    @prev_product := product
FROM report_combined
JOIN (SELECT @prev_product := '', @running := 0, @row_num := 0) vars
ORDER BY product, ipdate;
```

N.B. This is the warning generated by MySQL 8 when using this method:

> Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Consider alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s) INTO variables(s)'.

Another way of achieving this is to use a [RECURSIVE CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (nr, id, ipdate, product, market_value_1, calc) AS (
    SELECT
        1, id, ipdate, product, market_value_1,
        market_value_1/100 - 1
    FROM report_combined
    WHERE ipdate = '2021-01-01'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        cte.nr + 1, rc.id, rc.ipdate, rc.product, rc.market_value_1,
        rc.market_value_1/cte.calc - 1
    FROM cte
    JOIN report_combined rc
        ON cte.product = rc.product
        AND cte.ipdate + INTERVAL 1 DAY = rc.ipdate
        AND rc.ipdate <= '2021-12-31'
)
SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY product, nr;
```

From the manual:

> The first SELECT produces the initial row or rows for the CTE and does not refer to the CTE name. The second SELECT produces additional rows and recurses by referring to the CTE name in its FROM clause. Recursion ends when this part produces no new rows. Thus, a recursive CTE consists of a nonrecursive SELECT part followed by a recursive SELECT part.

This approach assumes that the date range has no gaps. If there are gaps, for weekends or bank holidays, then you could use another CTE to create a continuous sequence first.

Comment: Group by product, and date server as order by -  your select does not start count @ 1 and also does not reset the count to 1 after product changes

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Please update your question with sample data for more than one product and a valid calculation and I'll have another look.